# MassTransit - Consume method not called after message is sent

Tags: .net-core, masstransit

**MyApp.Application**

```
public class CreatePersonHandler : IConsumer<CreatePerson>
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public CreatePersonHandler(IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CreatePerson> context)
        {
            ...
            Person person = _mapper.Map<Person>(context.Message);
            _unitOfWork.Persons.Add(person);
        }
    }
```

**MyApp.API**
Startup.cs
...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Startup)));
   services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork >();
   services.AddMassTransit(x =>
   {
       x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
       x.AddConsumer<CreatePersonHandler>();    

       x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
       {
           cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("persons", e =>
           {
               e.ConfigureConsumer<CreatePersonHandler>(context);
           });
       });
    });

    services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
}
```

From the controller I'm sending message using IBus

```
 _bus.Send(new CreatePerson{ FirstName = "Bob "});
```

but I execute handler and I cannot hit the Consume method in the CreatePersonHandler class.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs are wonderful, they'd show you that `Send` is throwing an exception. Since you don't have a destinationAddress, you can't `Send` on the bus.

I'd suggest using `Publish` instead, so that the broker can route the message to the consumer for you.

Also, review the logs. Always start with the logs.

Comment: oh, I see now. I need to use  EndpointConvention.Map as a destination address in order to use bus.Send. I guess I need to dig deeper into docs. Many thanks.